# Convert date format

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I don't know how to search on the internet:

Problem: I get the date in this format:

> Mon Nov 14 13:30:00 MEZ 48472

and I would like to convert this with the following code but I dont know the start pattern:

`SimpleDateFormat formatEnde = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd. MMM k:mm", java.util.Locale.getDefault());`

I don't know, what does "48472" mean at the end and on the internet, I have not found anything.

My try is not working, because the pattern is not right:

`SimpleDateFormat formatStart = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z");`

Can you help me please or give a link to any information?

This is my code to get Date as String:

```
long date = messages[i].getReceivedDate().getTime();
java.util.Date dateTime=new java.util.Date((long)date*1000);
String datum = String.valueOf(dateTime);
```

Comment: Are you sure that **48472** is a part of the whole date?

Comment: You may try substring the incoming datetime and then convert it with any format you need, just a thought!

Comment: Do you know how this date is generated ? Give us a clue, since it does not look as any standard one or follow @F.sh suggestion. Substract in point which you know that is parsable...

Comment: @TodorKostov I have added the code, to get the information of time, at the top. It is incorrect?

Comment: Try the suggestion from @F.sh The rest of the format should look something like **EEE MMM yy hh:mm:ss Z**

Comment: Umm Tuba Ylm whats is your question? you already have a date using  `long date = messages[i].getReceivedDate().getTime();
java.util.Date dateTime=new java.util.Date((long)date*1000);` so why you need `String datum = String.valueOf(dateTime);`?  If you want to get the date formated, just use `formatEnde.format(dateTime)`

Comment: Thank you at all! I have solved it with a substring without the end of the part.Thank you @F.sh

Answer (score -1):

You may try substring the incoming datetime and then convert it with any format you need, just a thought!